# Reading data from a PDF file in Classic ASP

Tags: pdf, asp-classic

I need to read data inside a PDF file in an ASP page.
I will need convert the file to another format or is there another way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either have a text file or a COM library that can understand PDF files, such as http://www.asppdf.com/ (result from Google search, this is not a product recommendation, only an example).

Answer (score 1):

[Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) fits this scenario if a commercial library is an option for you. You can find examples for Visual Basic [here](http://amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1228).

*Usual disclaimer applies*